# Sporadic Cucumber timeouts on Jenkins due to AJAX requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, capybara

I'm having an issue with cucumber tests in our rails app (3.2.15) where they'll randomly time out in areas where we do a lot of AJAX requests on Jenkins.  We're using the selenium JS driver:

selenium-client (1.2.18)

selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)

Below, I click a save button that sends off an AJAX request:

```
05:05:05  And I follow "Save"  # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:66
```

...and the next thing I see in the Jenkins log is the timeout a few hours later (once it hits the timeout we specify - 3 hours):

```
07:52:01 Build timed out (after 180 minutes). Marking the build as failed.
07:52:01 Archiving artifacts
07:52:01 Robot results publisher started...
07:52:01 -Parsing output xml:
07:52:01 Failed!
07:52:01 /var/jenkins/workspace/user-interface_test/robot_results does not exist.
07:52:01  at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:483)
07:52:01  at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:460)
07:52:01  at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser$RobotParserCallable.invoke(RobotParser.java:65)
07:52:01  at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser$RobotParserCallable.invoke(RobotParser.java:51)
07:52:01  at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2415)
07:52:01  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
07:52:01  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
07:52:01  at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
07:52:01  at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
07:52:01  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
07:52:01  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07:52:01  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
07:52:01  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
07:52:01  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
07:52:01 Finished: FAILURE
```

Has anybody else seen this behavior and have any ideas about a fix?  I do notice that sometimes it seems to time out at the beginning of a Scenario in the same fashion.  When it fails at the beginning of a scenario, it has a bunch of "message type *_* arrived from server while idle" messages, too.

```
21:18:05   @javascript @ignore_browser_errors
21:18:05   Scenario: Doing some AJAX stuff on a page  # features/campaigns/guaranteed_media.feature:78
21:18:06 message type 0x54 arrived from server while idle
21:18:06 message type 0x43 arrived from server while idle
21:18:06 message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle
21:18:06 message type 0x43 arrived from server while idle
21:18:06 message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle
23:47:50 Build timed out (after 180 minutes). Marking the build as failed.
...followed by the same stack trace above...
```

Edit: (11/01/2013) Note that we have @ignore_browser_errors attached to this scenario because we're seeing a JS error in test that we do not see in development.

Comment: The JS error might be a clue, but in general these errors are the worst to debug - especially with Jenkins involved. In general it helps to run the test suite locally in exactly the same manner as Jenkins does and see if there's something that comes up.

Comment: There's always the wait_for_ajax hack that you can try and see if that helps: https://coderwall.com/p/aklybw

Answer (score 1):

It turns out our issue had to do with the postgres db connection adapter being shared between cucumber and the webserver.  We ended up turning off DB cleaning in between steps and require that our steps are written in an independent manner. This seems to be working much better.  After making that decision, I stumbled upon a potential workaround here:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/issues/166

Also, the database cleaner git page has a lot of good info:

https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner